# Android: Add OnTouch to a dynamic row to make Intent

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I've made the table to make rows dynamically. I'm trying to make onTouch event, and if it triggers then move on to another activity using intent. I can't make it to work it says:

**The method setClass(Context, Class) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnTouchListener(){}, Class)**

I've tried changing THIS to the name of the class, but It can't be found.

Here is the code

```
                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("TAREA_TOUCH", tarea.getIdtareasr() + " TO");

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(this, EditarTarea.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", tarea.getIdtareasr() + "");
                    startActivity(intent);

                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intent.setClass(NameOfYourActivity.this, EditarTarea.class);
```

Or

```
intent.setClass(NameOfYourActivity.getApplicationContext(), EditarTarea.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.setClass(this, EditarTarea.class);
```

Here "this" refers to the anonymous instance of the interface "OnTouchListener". For creating an intent, we need to pass Activity context.

So as Braj and Alexis Cartier said, please use :

```
intent.setClass(ClassName.this, EditarTarea.class);
```

Where "ClassName" refers to your current activity name.